# Does using retained Fragment breaks the idea of MVP pattern ,where Fragment/Activity represents like View?

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-java, rx-android

I want to handle orientation change via retained Fragment
I use MVP pattern 
if In Presenter I have the object of Observable (RxAndroid),
it means I should pass the observable to that Fragment
It doesn't mean that it breaks the rule of MVP pattern where Activity,Fragment represents View?

Comment: what exactly do you use the retained fragment for?

Answer (score 0):

In a particular implementation of MVP, it is common to retain the presenter across configuration change.

For this, people tend to use the following setups:

- Loaders (I do not like this one)
- hold the presenter inside a Retained fragment (quirky because Activity's `super.onCreate()` re-creates the fragment automatically, but otherwise works fine)
- retain the presenter via `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` with which you can return an object, and you can obtain it with `getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`.

---

Retained Fragment is part of the view, and it would manage the presenter's "lifecycle" in the sense that it would keep it from dying.

In this case, you generally subscribe/attach your view to the presenter, and unsubscribe/detach your view from the presenter depending on lifecycle events - commonly `onStart()/onStop()`, although I think `onCreate()/onDestroy()` and `onCreateView()/onDestroyView()` make more sense.

---

So no, it does not break the idea of MVP, as long as the retained fragment is part of your "view", or at least the presenter itself is agnostic to its existence.

However, using `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` is much easier.